# Gráfico Agrupado

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualización-de-datos, seaborn

Estoy practicando con una base de datos de titulaciones universitarias y tipos de abandono. En la columna COD_TITUL están el nombre de las titulaciones, de forma que distintos estudiantes pueden cursar la misma, y en la columna SITUACION se le ha asignado a cada estudiante una categoría, si está estudiando, si ha abandonado, etc.

Lo que quiero conseguir es graficar en el eje Y el nombre de las titulaciones, en el eje X la cantidad de alumnos matriculados en cada una, y como Hue la situación.

Lo primero lo he conseguido, el problema es conseguir que se muestre el HUE.

```
df = pd.read_csv(directorio + "csv.csv", sep = ";")

conteo = df.COD_TITUL.value_counts()

sns.barplot(x = list(df.COD_TITUL.value_counts()), y = list(df.COD_TITUL.value_counts().index)
            ,orient = "h", data = df, hue = "SITUACION")
```

El error es:

```
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 786, in get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)

KeyError: '6201 - Psicología'
```

Parece que no consigue agrupar correctamente. ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: ¿podrías suministrar un enlace a tu csv, o si éste no puede publicarse, a uno similar, quizás con datos generados al azar? Así podré hacer algunos experimentos con esos datos. Creo que la solución pasará por manipular el dataframe una vez leido el csv para que tenga la estructura que permita a seaborn pintarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que la solución más simple es usar un `histplot()` que te puede computar él mismo las agrupaciones y contadores que necesitas:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df =pd.read_csv("csv_situacion_stackover.csv", sep=";")
# Corregir un problema con una de las categorías
df.SITUACION = df.SITUACION.replace({"#Â¡NULO!": "Nulo"})

# Preparar tamaño y estilo de la figura
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(6,10)})
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

# Crear la figura
sns.histplot(df, y='COD_TITUL', hue='SITUACION',  multiple='stack', shrink=0.9)
```

Resultado:

[image: Figura]

Otra posibilidad es crear tú mismo los contadores necesarios para lo cual deberías usar `groupby()` de pandas para crear grupos por titulación y por situación:

```
aux = df.groupby(["COD_TITUL", "SITUACION"]).CURSO.count().reset_index()
aux = aux.rename(columns={"CURSO": "Alumnos"})
```

Esto produce un dataframe como el siguiente:

[image: Tabla]

El cual ya puedes dibujar con `sns.barplot()`:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(6,10)})
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

sns.barplot(data=aux, y="COD_TITUL", x="Alumnos", hue="SITUACION", orient="h")
```

si bien en esta ocasión las barras no salen apiladas en cada titulación, sino una al lado de otra y no he encontrado forma de apilarlas.

[image: Grafica]